# Creating a view by Putting results of rounded coalesce columns of table(s), in another column from a different table

Tags: sql, sql-server

Below are the Tables that I am trying to merge into one single result.

```
    **MainTable**
            --------------------------------------------------------------
            ID    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4   ClassType     UserName
            --------------------------------------------------------------
            1      1       0      NULL     1       A           Kate
            2      0       1       1       1       C           Leo
            3      1       1       0       0       D           Mark
            4      1       0       1       1       B           Cathy
            5      0      NULL    NULL     1       A           Lex
            6      1       1      NULL     1       B           Dwight
            7      0       0      NULL     0       C           Jim
            --------------------------------------------------------------
 

**ClassA Table**
            --------------------------------------------------------------
            ID    Val1    Val2   Val3    Val4  ClassType     UserName
            --------------------------------------------------------------
            1      1       1       1       1       A           Kate
            2      0       1       1       1       A           Lex
            --------------------------------------------------------------

**ClassB Table**
            --------------------------------------------------------------
            ID    Val1    Val2   Val3    Val4  ClassType     UserName
            --------------------------------------------------------------
            1      1       0       1       1       B           Cathy
            2      0       1       1       1       B           Dwight
            --------------------------------------------------------------


**ClassC Table**
            --------------------------------------------------------------
            ID    Val1    Val2   Val3    Val4  ClassType     UserName
            --------------------------------------------------------------
            1      1       0       1       1       C           Leo
            2      0       1       1       1       C           Jim
            --------------------------------------------------------------

**ClassD Table**
            --------------------------------------------------------------
            ID    Val1    Val2   Val3    Val4  ClassType     UserName
            --------------------------------------------------------------
            1      1       0       1       1       C           Mark
            --------------------------------------------------------------
```

What I want to achieve is something like this

```
Select ID, Col1, Col2 , Col3, Col4, ClassType, (select Round((100.00*(COALESCE(Val1,0) +
COALESCE(Val2,0) +
COALESCE(Val3,0) +
COALESCE(Val4,0)) / 4), 0) as TotalVal from @TableName where username = @Username) as TotalVal , UserName
Where UserName = @Username And ClassType = @ClassType
```

Where I can put the total of the rounded val columns in each Class Table in `as TotalVal`  depending on what `ClassType` in the `MainTable`   that I am looking for. I tried including all the tables in the query but I think that would be inefficient since I will be calling all the tables even when I dont need it since I am calling only the 1 table depending on the class type I think it would be better if there would like an "if condition" or "case". Also I am going to make the select statement above or the query as a view. But it doesnt work correctly.

What should I do to achieve the results below using the query above? Or maybe there is more efficient way to achieve the results below using a different approach?

```
    **Result of Query**
            --------------------------------------------------------------------------
            ID    Col1    Col2    Col3    Col4   ClassType   TotalVal     UserName
            --------------------------------------------------------------------------
            1      1       0      NULL     1       A          100.00         Kate
            --------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Im kinda new to SQL and I do not know the terminology so please excuse me for that. Please correct me if there is wrong in my question. I wanted to learn. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try a UNION of the various tables to make them into on set of data like this ...

```
DECLARE
    @TableName varchar(50) = 'ClassA',
    @UserName varchar(50) = 'Kate',
    @ClassType varchar(50) = 'A'


;WITH MainTable AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
            (1, 1, 0, NULL, 1, 'A', 'Kate'),
            (2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 'C', 'Leo'),
            (3, 1, 1, 0, 0, 'D', 'Mark'),
            (4, 1, 0, 1, 1, 'B', 'Cathy'),
            (5, 0, NULL, NULL, 1, 'A', 'Lex'),
            (6, 1, 1, NULL, 1, 'B', 'Dwight'),
            (7, 0, 0, NULL, 0, 'C', 'Jim')
    ) S(ID, Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4, ClassType, UserName)
), ClassA AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
            (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 'A', 'Kate'),
            (2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 'A', 'Lex')
    ) S(ID, Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, ClassType, UserName)
), ClassB AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
            (1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 'B', 'Cathy'),
            (2, 0, 1, 1, 1, 'B', 'Dwight')
    ) S(ID, Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, ClassType, UserName)
), ClassC AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
            (1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 'C', 'Leo'),
            (2, 0, 0, 1, 1, 'C', 'Jim')
    ) S(ID, Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, ClassType, UserName)
), ClassD AS (
    SELECT * FROM (VALUES
            (1, 1, 0, 1, 1, 'D', 'Mark')
    ) S(ID, Val1, Val2, Val3, Val4, ClassType, UserName)
)

SELECT
    M.ID, M.Col1, M.Col2 , M.Col3, M.Col4, M.ClassType, U.TotalVal
FROM
    MainTable M
    JOIN (
        SELECT UserName, 'ClassA' TableName, ROUND((25 * (ISNULL(Val1, 0) + ISNULL(Val2, 0) + ISNULL(Val3, 0) + ISNULL(Val4, 0))), 0) TotalVal FROM ClassA UNION ALL
        SELECT UserName, 'ClassB' TableName, ROUND((25 * (ISNULL(Val1, 0) + ISNULL(Val2, 0) + ISNULL(Val3, 0) + ISNULL(Val4, 0))), 0) TotalVal FROM ClassB UNION ALL
        SELECT UserName, 'ClassC' TableName, ROUND((25 * (ISNULL(Val1, 0) + ISNULL(Val2, 0) + ISNULL(Val3, 0) + ISNULL(Val4, 0))), 0) TotalVal FROM ClassC UNION ALL
        SELECT UserName, 'ClassD' TableName, ROUND((25 * (ISNULL(Val1, 0) + ISNULL(Val2, 0) + ISNULL(Val3, 0) + ISNULL(Val4, 0))), 0) TotalVal FROM ClassD
    ) U ON
        U.UserName = M.UserName AND
        U.TableName = @TableName
WHERE
    
    M.UserName = @UserName AND
    M.ClassType = @ClassType
```

Frankly looking at the data, I would expect you wouldn't search by `TableName` so much as JOIN the UNION based on the `ClassType` like this ... (replace the previous SELECT statement with this one)

```
SELECT
    M.ID, M.Col1, M.Col2 , M.Col3, M.Col4, M.ClassType, U.TotalVal
FROM
    MainTable M
    JOIN (
        SELECT UserName, ClassType, ROUND((25 * (ISNULL(Val1, 0) + ISNULL(Val2, 0) + ISNULL(Val3, 0) + ISNULL(Val4, 0))), 0) TotalVal FROM ClassA UNION ALL
        SELECT UserName, ClassType, ROUND((25 * (ISNULL(Val1, 0) + ISNULL(Val2, 0) + ISNULL(Val3, 0) + ISNULL(Val4, 0))), 0) TotalVal FROM ClassB UNION ALL
        SELECT UserName, ClassType, ROUND((25 * (ISNULL(Val1, 0) + ISNULL(Val2, 0) + ISNULL(Val3, 0) + ISNULL(Val4, 0))), 0) TotalVal FROM ClassC UNION ALL
        SELECT UserName, ClassType, ROUND((25 * (ISNULL(Val1, 0) + ISNULL(Val2, 0) + ISNULL(Val3, 0) + ISNULL(Val4, 0))), 0) TotalVal FROM ClassD
    ) U ON
        U.UserName = M.UserName AND
        U.ClassType = M.ClassType
WHERE
    
    M.UserName = @UserName AND
    M.ClassType = @ClassType
```